# Why is listening on port with Netcat not working

Tags: networking, netcat

I am running the following command on Ubuntu:

```
nc -l -p 5004 -v  >> /home/anders/Dropbox/netcatFiles/test
```

which includes a command to make it listen at 5004.

I am sending a RTP-stream to port 5004 using VLC. When I am observing the loopback-interface in Wireshark I notice ICMP-packets with the message 'Destination unreachable'.

Opening another VLC and telling it to play the incoming data at port 5004, it all works, and the stream is played.

What should I do in order to get Netcat to listen at port 5004?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you need to add the " -u " parameter to make it listen on UDP.

By default, netcat works in TCP mode, but RTP protocol is UDP based.

> "The Transmission Control Protocol (TCP), although standardized for
>   RTP use,[5] is not normally used in RTP application because TCP favors
>   reliability over timeliness. Instead the majority of the RTP
>   implementations are built on the User Datagram Protocol (UDP)"

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol

Comment: Thanks!
The following works:
nc -u -l -p 5004 -v >> /home/anders/Dropbox/netcatFiles/test

Comment: I did a quick check, and Harald Brinkhof is correct. "-l -p 5004" shouldn't be working. I suspect you have an old version of netcat. The one I have, that supports your -p 5004 syntax, reports version 1.10, while on another box I have a version which looks newer (more options, etc.) which has the same manual page Harald quotes.

Answer (score 8):

don't use -p ([man nc (1)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man1/nc.1.html))

> -p source_port
>                Specifies the source port nc should use, subject to privilege restrictions and availability.  It is an error to use this option in con‐
>                junction with the -l option.

so just specify

```
nc -l 5004 -v  >> /home/anders/Dropbox/netcatFiles/test
```

Comment: However, when I did the above command it didn't work. Status:
Warning: Inverse name lookup failed for `0.0.19.140'

and when I do:
nc -u -l -p 5004 -v  >> /home/anders/Dropbox/netcatFiles/test
it works.
I get the status:
Received packet from 127.0.0.1:32843 -> 127.0.0.1:5004 (local)

Comment: i tested with `nc -l 5004 >> output.txt` for the listener and `echo "tester" | nc 127.0.0.1 5004` for the sender. Worked fine though it does need the host for the sender.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and your comment!!

Based on Isernis latest comment and some research I did after receiving it:
The manual you linked to, and my version of nc, seems to be for an old version of nc. The manual reads:
  nc -l -p port [-options] [hostname] [port]

Comment: ubuntu actually has (or at least used to have) 2 netcat packages: one openbsd nc based and the other the 'traditional' one probably called netcat-traditional. It might be that there's some discrepancy between those 2 versions.

Comment: I'm not sure what the opposite of thank you is, but I needed to add `-p` for my version to work: `netcat (The GNU Netcat) 0.7.1`. Seems like I'd installed it via Macports on Mac OS X (hint being that it was located here `/opt/local/libexec/gnubin/nc`).